# What does the user_interface param in tinyMCE.execCommand do?

Tags: tinymce

tinyMCE.execCommand accepts a boolean `user_interface` parameter, and I've been trying to figure out what the difference is when it's called with `true` or `false`.  The source seems to call it with `false` consistently, and the JSDoc description says `True/false state if a UI (dialog) should be presented or not.`.  I've tried calling it with true and false and don't notice anything different.  What is actually supposed to happen or allowed to happen if it's `true`?  Can an example be provided?

Answer (score 1):

That parameter is no longer used in TinyMCE.  It is a holdover from an older TinyMCE where this was valid parameter - its not been removed for compatibility issues.

Comment: Would've been nice to see it marked as such, or deprecated at the very least https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editorcommands/#execcommand